# Gallery Pro Table Into mysql at wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

How I can reach `Gallery Pro` Plugin Table Into `mysql` at `wordpress` ?

I Need To find `Gallery Pro` Plugin Query To show show Gallery Images On App Via Rest API

At Admin Panel I Add New Image Into Gallery With Short Code `[WG id=1606]`
It Make Row Into `wp_posts` Table

When I Add Image From PC It Add New Row With `post_parent = '1606'`

But When I Add Image Allready Uploaded On Server It Doesn't Add Any Row To `wp_posts` Table

Comment: Have you asked them?

Comment: @Strawberry How i can ask them ?

Comment: Well, they have a support page. I'd start there. https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/gallery-pro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found Solution :

```
    $lksg_Id = '1606';
    $TotalImg =  get_post_meta( $lksg_Id, 'lksg_total_images_count', true );
    $lksg_Gallery_Settings = "lksg_Gallery_Settings_".$lksg_Id;
    $lksg_AllPhotosDetails = unserialize(base64_decode(get_post_meta( $lksg_Id, 'lksg_all_photos_details', true)));
    // echo 'All Photos Details : <br /> ' . var_dump($lksg_AllPhotosDetails) . '<br /><br /><br />';
    if(count($lksg_Gallery_setting)) {
        $lk_gallery_title       =   $lksg_Gallery_setting['lk_gallery_title'];
        $lk_show_image_label        =   $lksg_Gallery_setting['lk_show_image_label'];
        $lk_Gallery_Layout      =   $lksg_Gallery_setting['lk_Gallery_Layout'];
        $wgp_Color          =   $lksg_Gallery_setting['wgp_Color'];
        $lk_label_Color             =       $lksg_Gallery_setting['lk_label_Color'];
        $lk_desc_font_Color         =       $lksg_Gallery_setting['lk_desc_font_Color'];
        $lk_btn_Color               =       $lksg_Gallery_setting['lk_btn_Color'];
        $lk_btn_font_Color      =       $lksg_Gallery_setting['lk_btn_font_Color'];
        $lk_font_style          =       $lksg_Gallery_setting['lk_font_style'];
        $lk_Custom_CSS          =       $lksg_Gallery_setting['lk_Custom_CSS'];
        $lk_show_img_desc       =       $lksg_Gallery_setting['lk_show_img_desc'];
        $lk_Light_Box           =       $lksg_Gallery_setting['lk_Light_Box'];
        $lk_open_link           =       $lksg_Gallery_setting['lk_open_link'];
        $lk_button_title        =       $lksg_Gallery_setting['lk_button_title'];
    }
    // echo 'Gallery setting : ' . var_dump($lksg_Gallery_setting) . '<br /><br /><br />';
    // echo 'Total Img : ' . var_dump($TotalImg) . '<br /><br /><br />';
    $results = array();
    if($TotalImg) {
        foreach($lksg_AllPhotosDetails as $data) {
            // echo 'data : <br /> '  . var_dump($data) . '<br /><br /><br />';
            $item = new stdclass();
            // $item->id = $data->ID;
            $item->title = $data['lksg_image_label'];
            $item->content = $data['img_desc'];
            $item->image = $data['lksg_image_url'];
            $item->tbn = $data['lksg_img_medium'];
            $results[] = $item;
        }
    }
    // Finally Return Array As Json String
```